Batch apex class from a managed package is running on an inactive user
We use ActiveCampaign's Salesforce integration, which includes an Apex Class called contactDataBatch. It runs hourly and does some of the sync work between SF and AC.
For months, the Apex Jobs running from this class have been failing due an inactive user error. When we pull up the Apex Jobs in Setup, sure enough this class is running on a long-inactive user.
I can't figure out how to get this to switch to an active user or integration user. There doesn't seem to be anything on the AC side that's causing this. Any ideas?

Can you check the below steps permsisons and settings User Permissions: Ensure that the Apex Jobs are running under an active user with the necessary permissions. Update the user's profile or role as needed. Scheduled Jobs: Check the scheduled job settings in Salesforce. Change the user context to an active user if possible. Integration Settings: Review ActiveCampaign integration settings to ensure there's nothing causing the job to run under an inactive user. Support: If the issue persists, contact ActiveCampaign support for assistance and insights.

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you contacted the vendor's support?

The solution here was in the ActiveCampaign settings inside Salesforce. I had to remove the Scheduled Job from there, then restart it from an active user. And now it works fine.
